# Java static linking of user modules without building a JRE runtime image

Tags: java, static-linking, java-module, jlink

Since java 9 I can use jlink to create a custom Java runtime image that contains all modules required for my application, and only them.

This can serve as a kind of static linking tool for Java, reducing the chance of ClassNotFoundException occurring due to a missing, moved or deleted library.

Is there a way to perform this kind of static link to only package the user defined modules as one unit without creating a JRE runtime image?

Comment: Isn't that what typical build tools do, like maven or gradle?

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky That's a good point, build tools can package the artifacts together.  I'm not sure if that qualifies as static linking.